# Help with Python strings

Tags: python, string

I have a program which reads commands from a text file

for example, the command syntax will be as follows and is a string

`'index command param1 param2 param3'`

The number of parameters is variable from 0 up to 3
index is an integer
command is a string
all the params are integers

I would like  to split them so that I have a list as follows

`[index,'command',params[]]`

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Will the string contain spaces?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure if it's the best way, but here's one way:

```
lines = open('file.txt')
for line in lines:
   as_list = line.split()
   result = [as_list[0], as_list[1], as_list[2:]]
   print result
```

Result will contain

```
['index', 'command', ['param1', 'param2', 'param3']]
```

Comment: @Amit: Added file processing steps

Comment: Thanks, very much everybody, you all have been a great help

Answer (score 5):

```
def add_command(index, command, *params):
    index = int(index)
    #do what you need to with index, command and params here

with open('commands.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        add_command(*line.split())
```

Answer (score 2):

i typically write:

```
lines = open('a.txt').readlines()
for line in lines:
    para = lines.split()
    index = int(para[0])
    command = para[1]
    para1 = float(para[2])
    ...
```

Comment: I'd recommend the first two lines be `f = open(filename)` and `for line in f:`, which avoids reading the whole file into memory.

Comment: @Mike, yeah, but usually a parameter file is not big... and a `print lines' could direct see if the file loads correctly or not..

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the file
2. Read each line and parse the line via `line.split( )`

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> for line in open("file"):
...     line=line.rstrip().split(" ",2)
...     line[0]=int(line[0])
...     line[2]=line[2].split()
...     print line
...
[1, 'command', ['param1', 'param2', 'param3']]
```

Comment: I like the solution but it doesnt work if there are are zero parameters in the command

Comment: its rather easy to insert code for checking. you can check whether length of list is always 3 and then do the necessary. Or use try/except etc etc...many ways...

Answer (score 1):

If you use **Python 3+**, then following should be enough as indicated in [PEP 3132: Extended Iterable Unpacking](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/):

```
(index,command,*parameters) = line.split()
```

---

Otherwise, I like solution from James best:

```
def add_command(index, command, *params):
    ...
```

Comment: you don't need brackets there in the unpacking version

Answer (score 0):

The Answer provided by **cb160** is correct and smart way, But, I did it in this way.
In **cb160**'s code, Only thing is index should be in Integer format, as you have mentioned.

In my below code, I added exceptions for empty lines in input file if there are any.

```
#Example Input File: (file content)
"""
1 command1 parm1a parm1b parm1c
2 command2 parm2a parm2b parm2c

3 command3 parm3a parm3b parm3c

"""

li = []

for line in open('list_of_commands.txt'):
  try:
    lis = line.split()
    li.append([int(lis[0]),lis[1], lis[2:]])
  except IndexError:
    pass    # do nothing if empty lines are found

print li
```

Output

```
[1, 'command1', ['parm1a', 'parm1b', 'parm1c']]
[2, 'command2', ['parm2a', 'parm2b', 'parm2c']]
[3, 'command3', ['parm3a', 'parm3b', 'parm3c']]
```

let me know if I missed anything.

Thanks

Comment: why are you splitting a single line three times? along with empty lines you're catching partial lines. I'd say this code is rather inferior to already posted versions.

Comment: @SilentGhose edited my code now, Thanks for suggesting. Yah, It was very unpythonic. Is it ok now?

Comment: it's better, but you don't need to "declare" `lin`.

Comment: we shall assume that `list_of_commands.txt` is actually a string ;)

Comment: I've corrected a few bits, removing redundant 4th line and `.readlines` method, as well as producing actual output